# Convert python file into exe using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, auto-py-to-exe

I have just finished a project where I have made a connect 4 game and am trying to convert it to an exe file using auto-py-to-exe.

I want to use the one-file option, however every time it finishes and I run it, it would come up with an error:

`Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: No file 'Assets/icon.png' found in working directory '...'`

Then in the box it says:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
 `File "main.py", line 32, in <module>`
`FileNotFoundError: No file 'Assets/window-icon.png' found in working directory '...'.`

I've tried quite a few alterations, e.g. not using the image, but then it would come up with the same error but for a different added file.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: 
I've tried it again by using the os module and giving the full directories to all the files in main.py, but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: YOu said: `I've tried quite a few alterations, e.g. not using the image, but then it would come up with the same error but for a different added file.` Are you telling it to use an icon and pointing it (auto-py-to-exe) to these icon files in the UI or CLI or json config? If so, ensure that you are including the absolute path to the file.

Comment: I’ve used pygame for making the game and have an ico for the exe and a png for the pygame window. 

Also, when I put it in one-directory, it worked perfectly fine. It’s just that one-file isn’t working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing this problem then I got the solutions from analysing other threads.
You have to update your script by adding this function

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
     """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path=getattr(sys,'_MEIPASS',os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
     return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

and changing address of every additional files used in your script

for example

```
icon = resource_path("game.icon")
```

You just have to use auto-py-to-exe just like shown below

[Showing the options you can just use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cprfv.jpg)

Add all the files used in the Additional File section of it and make sure that the period(.) is there in the destination 
That's it !